R: 'area' function for las-file
I want to work on this project: https://gitlab.gwdg.de/tanja.kempen/skidtrail-detection/-/blob/main/README.md?ref_type=heads where I'm using the SkidTrail_Preprocessing.R R-Script.
Software: RStudio 2024.04.2 Build 764;
lidR: 4.1.1;
spdata: 2.3.1;
spDataLarge: 2.1.1;
sp: 2.1-4;
raster: 3.6-26;
sf: 1.0-16;
terra: 1.7-78;
R: 4.4.0
I want to use the function "area" for a las-file. The las-file is from my local administration.
Then I get this error:
> area(las_ground)
Fehler: kann keine vererbte Methode finden für Funktion ‘area’ für Signatur ‘x = "LAS"’
(Error: cannot find inherited method for fonction 'area' for signatur 'x = "LAS"')

Maybe the cause is the missing rgdal library? It's not available any more.

Works for me even without rgdal. Note I can't find the data file used in that example (data/lasfile.laz is not in that repository) so I'm using a laz file supplied with the lidR package. Have you got the latest versions of everything? Give the versions of R and packages in your question and don't bother with the RStudio version, which is irrelevant.

Thanks, I've updated the versions. It should be fine, because I recently installed them. Update-check tells me, everything is up to date.

The terra package creates its own area function that is incompatible with working out areas of las objects. From a clean R session:
> library(lidR)
lidR 4.1.1 using 4 threads. Help on <gis.stackexchange.com>. Bug report on <github.com/r-lidar/lidR>.
> LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
     las = readLAS(LASfile)
> area(las)
[1] 51572

So area works fine there. Now attach terra:
> library(terra)
terra 1.7.78

Attaching package: ‘terra’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:lidR’:

    area, crs, crs<-, is.empty

See the "masked" working? Now terra is earlier in your search path, you'll get terra::area and not lidR::area:
> area(las)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘area’ for signature ‘"LAS"’

as a fix, always explicitly use the package function:
> lidR::area(las)
[1] 51572
 

for las objects, and terra::area(r) for any terra objects.

@Spacedman anwser is correct but let me add some insight
lidR::st_area() extends sf::st_area() and does not clash with sf
library(lidR)
library(sf)

LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
las = readLAS(LASfile)
st_area(las)

You can get the area without reading the entiere file. It gives you the area of the bounding box and may be less accurate.
las = readLASheader(LASfile)
st_area(las)

